# var becomes undefined inside Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This is probably something a very small problem but I can't find its solution so please bear with me!

I don't understand why at `const body = ctx.request.body` ctx becomes undefined. Before it carried over `this` from the `create()` function which calls `createEntity()`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm calling a function `createEntity`like this:

```
module.exports = {
  createEntity: () => {
    var ctx = this  // both ctx and this are fine
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const body = ctx.request.body  // <-- ctx is undefined
      resolve();
    })
  }
}
```

`create()` calls `createEntity()`. It is a generator function wrapped with `co()`via Koa.js

```
create: function * () {
    this.body = yield createEntity.call(this)
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's a screenshot why I thought `this` is fine after calling `createEntity`:
[image]

Comment: You're using an arrow function, why not just use `const body = this.request.body`?

Comment: you need to write it like: `createInvoice(){ ... }`

Comment: `this` is evaluated incorrectly on the screenshot, it looks like a Jetpack product bug.

Comment: @towerofnix Please look at response of Felix Kling.

Comment: @estus What is Jetpack? I thought VSCode is using the default node debugger.

Comment: @Hedge Confused it with Webstorm debugger appearance. Sure, Node debugger is used somehow, but this doesn't mean that IDE uses it the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> both ctx and this are fine

I doubt that. You are using an **arrow function**. You cannot set an arrow function's `this` via `call` because an arrow doesn't have an own `this` <sup>1</sup>.

**Use a normal function instead.**

See also [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

---

1: `this` inside `createEntity` refers to the top-level `this` of the module, which is `module.exports`:

```
this;        // <------------|
module.exports = {           |
  createEntity: () => {      |
    var ctx = this     // ---|
  }
}
console.log(this === module.exports); // true
```

Comment: Yeah that was a dumb mistake. Please check out my screenshot in the original question why I thought `this` was fine.

Comment: Object doesn't mean they are the same. If you have var object = {} it is also an Object but has nothing inside

Answer (score 1):

By assigning an arrow function to `createEntity`, [`this` inside the arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Invoked_through_call_or_apply) is assigned to the value of `this` in the scope where the arrow function was declared, which is probably the global object (therefore if you're using `use strict`, `this` will be `undefined`), and it'll stay that way even if you invoke the function using `call`.

Use a common function expression instead

```
createEntity: function () {
    ...
}
```